# An example of a sequence in $l_4$ but not in $l_3$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can you provide an example of a sequence in $l_4$ but not in $l_3$?

Comment: Hint: Try to think about the harmonic series.

Comment: What about $\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}$?

Comment: That is an extremely good example.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. We have $x := (\frac 1n) \in \bigcap_{p > 1}\ell^p \setminus \ell^1$. Now consider $(x_n^q)$ for the right $q$.